# Adding values to a JList

Tags: java

I have 2 classes, a view where all my controls are placed for my gui and another one for my code.

But how do I add values to the `JList`? I can only do it from the GUI class (first class mentioned below) itself, but that's not a suitable spot.

#### First class

```
private JList userList;
userList = new JList(ce.data); // where data is the datalist model in my 2nd class
```

#### Second class (holds all the future calculations, arrays, etc.)

```
private String[] testList;
DefaultListModel data = new DefaultListModel();

public void AddValuesList()
{
    testList = new String[] {"user1", "user2"};

    for (int i=0; i < testList.length; i++)
    {
        this.data.add(i, testLijst[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?  The JList is a GUI item, but the ListModel is the model for it, so it seems like you ought to be able to make the two interact appropriately - add helper methods as necessary.

Comment: I can perfectly add values from the array if i stay in 1 file, but they have to be split up amongst 2 files, and not sure why my data does not get "filled" into data. I only get a blanco JList now insteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it really is how justkt laid out.  In your second class add a getter for the list model (e.g. `DefaultListModel`), create your `JList` with that model (or set it after creation of the `JList`), then add your values to the list model.  Looks like from your example the only thing you are missing is setting the list model on the `JList`.  Once that is done your JList will pick up the values you add.

So it would be something like (sorry about the formatting...):

```
class TestModel {

private DefaultListModel lm_;

  public TestModel() {
    lm_ = new DefaultListModel();

    String[] testList = new String[] {"user1", "user2"};

    for(int i=0; i < testList.length; i++) {
      lm_.add(i, testList[i]);
    }
  }

  public ListModel getListModel() {
    return lm_;
  }
}

public class Test {

  public Test() {

    TestModel tm = new TestModel();

    JList list = new JList(tm.getListModel());
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the well written input. Although where does the ListModel come from, i have been trying similar things but cannot get the lm returned. Getting a error datamodel must be non null.

Comment: Sounds like you are not new'ing the list model before you are calling the getter for the list model.  Just to make sure, in the constructor of your model class, create the list model and make sure you are not declaring the list model again (making a local var in the constructor that is the same name as your member list model).  Does that make sense?  If not maybe post your exact code (or a scaled down version that includes your class declaration.)

Comment: The Jlist is declared only once as private in my first class. Then it gets called like this: userList = new JList(ce.getListModel());. But the thing i do not really understand where do you get ListModel from the getListModel method? Public ..... getListmodel(), where the ... are where i am clueless. Regards

Comment: Oh, so what you do is in your second class, declare a member var of type `DefaultListModel` (which implements `ListModel`), new that member var up in the constructor (or at declaration).  Set your values into the list model, then return that in your getter.  So in the code I posted above (in TestModel), lm_ is what I'm referring to.  So in the getListModel, you can have a return type of DefaultListModel or it's interface ListModel.  I usually do the highest level (in this case ListModel) so if you need to swap it out later, you don't have to change the API.  Any clearer?

Comment: And BTW, you can still set or remove values in lm_ later; you don't have to just add them before you return the list model.  The JList will pick the changes up.

Comment: Tonz, if you are still fuzzy about what I'm stating, drop me a line at barric90@yahoo.com.  I'll be able to send you a more complete code example.